# Labelled Column not recognised by a Sub in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, label

I have named columns in my Excel Workbook. I have then written VBA script to analyse the data and I begin by labelling the named columns (Game, Hole and Dte in Example 1 below). I'm then running a for and if loop on the data. When I run the loop in the main Sub as in Example 1 it works fine. However, when I run the loop in its own Sub (Example 2 below) I get an 'application-defined or object-defined error' because it's not recognising my column 'Hole'. The 'Hole' column is the sixth in the Excel worksheet so when I change the code in Example 2 to refer to " If Sheets("37 Rounds Stacked").Cells(i, 6) < 4 " then it does work so it's obviously losing my labelling of the column once I have the loop in a Sub where I don't define the columns.

Can anyone help me to understand why and how to fix it?

**Example 1:**

```
Sub DRVE()
Game = Range("Round").Column
Hole = Range("Hole").Column
Dte = Range("Date").Column

Dim x As Long
x = 0
For i = 2 To 739
    If Sheets("37 Rounds Stacked").Cells(i, Hole) < 4 Then
            x = x + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

**Example 2:**

```
Sub DRVE()
Game = Range("Round").Column
Hole = Range("Hole").Column
Dte = Range("Date").Column

End Sub

Sub DRVE2()

Dim x As Long
x = 0
For i = 2 To 739
    If Sheets("37 Rounds Stacked").Cells(i, Hole) < 4 Then
            x = x + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a problem of scope. `DRVE2` doesn't know anything about `Hole` in `DRVE`. You may want to start by reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility). You should also add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables.

Comment: @BigBen thanks very much, I read through that, added Option Explicit and declared Hole as a String at the very start of the module. It still didn't work for me and then I even tried changing the code in Example 2 to the following and still got the same error. Again it works if I use 6 instead of Hole. Is it something to do with using the variable as a column identifier? Code changed to: `Dim x As Long Dim i As Long Dim Hole As String Hole = Range("Hole").Column x = 0 For i = 2 To 738     If Sheets("37 Rounds Stacked").Cells(i, Hole) < 18 Then             x = x + 1     End If Next i`

Comment: What is the value in the Immediate Window if you `Debug.Print Hole` before attempting to use it? Also, `Hole` should be a `Long`.

Comment: @BigBen thank so much for the help. When I change it to Dim Hole as Long at the very start of the module it works perfectly. The value in the Immediate Window was 6 which is what I guess you were expecting (or hoping!). Any idea why it didn't work when I had defined it as String?

Comment: Because you were passing it a string that looked like a number, not an actual number.